# Constant-correctness with function members

Tags: c++, const-correctness

The class `TestConst` has a member `set` of type `std::function<void(double)>`.
The `setter` method is marked as `const` but it still *modifies* the internal private variable `m_value`.

```
class TestConst {
public:
    void setter(double v) const {
        set(v);
    }
    
private:
    double m_value = 1;
    std::function<void(double)> set = [this](double v) {m_value = v;};
};
```

Why does the compiler (`g++ 10.2`) allows that without any errors or warnings?

Comment: `const` as a member function specifier doesn't mean "the object won't be changed by this function", it means "`this` is a const pointer in this function". The function can still change the object via another pointer/reference to the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capture of `this` isn't const, and the member isn't modified by `*this` but through an indirection.

This is the same situation:

```
class TestConst {
public:
    void setter(double v) const {
        sneaky.set(v);
    }
    
private:
    double m_value = 1;
    struct
    {
         TestConst* that;
         void set(double v) const { that->m_value = v; }
    } sneaky{ this };
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be aware of this 'trick' and emit, at least, a warning?

Comment: @AlQuemist as soon as we solve the halting problem, sure.

Comment: @AlQuemist It's impossible in general, and very difficult in special cases except for very trivial ones.

Comment: Isn't the problem apparent from the non-constness of the captured `this`?

Comment: In this very trivial case, yes. Add some more indirection or move the definition of `set` to a different file and it's no longer apparent.

Comment: I am talking precisely about this _particular_ case where the detection of the violation of const-correctness is very explicit. I'm already aware that, in general, in a language like C++, detection of all violations of const-correctness is impossible.

Comment: An extremely special case like this usually isn't worth the effort. It is very rare that the compiler will encounter a capturing lambda that modifies a member *and* is called from a const member function of the same object *and* all of this can be determined at compile time. If you feel that your wellbeing depends on it, I'm sure the g++ team wouldn't mind a contribution.

Comment: I guess the simple rule would be that when a lambdas captures a non-const `this` pointer, then mutation is possible. Therefore, a warning of const-violation is in order.

Comment: Capturing `this` is so common that everyone would disable that warning (or curse you for not making it possible to disable only that warning).

Comment: @AlQuemist It is a problem in your view, because you want `const` to mean "the object won't be changed by this function". If `const` was defined the way you want, then capturing the non-const `this` could violate this promise and so be a potentially diagnosable error. But "const" means something else.  So there is no problem to be diagnosed.

Comment: @n. m. : afaiu, a `const` member function is a member function that guarantees it will not modify the object or call any non-const member functions.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. A `const` member function will not modify the object **through the implicit parameter**. The implicit parameter is no different from any other parameter. There is no guarantee that a function will not modify an object simply because it happens to be passed a `const` pointer to that object. It may have another, non-`const` pointer to the same object, and no promise is made about it.